Simplest code of Fast UI can not work. I'm very curious as to how this is done?
The following code is the simplest code on the planet, but Fast UI cannot run, and the style of the DataGrid is completely lost. I am curious how an excellent tool like VSCode was born. Is the core architecture of Fast UI based on Windows Vista?
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@microsoft/fast-components/dist/fast-components.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            (function () {
                const sampleGrid = document.getElementById('samplegrid');
                sampleGrid.rowsData = [
                    {
                        item1: 'value 1-1',
                        item2: 'value 2-1',
                        item3: 'value 4-1',
                        item4: 'value 5-1',
                    }
                ];
            })();
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <fast-data-grid id="samplegrid"></fast-data-grid>
</body>

</html>

